# how to make 3 columns using imacros?

Tags: imacros

I'm trying to retrieve the data of a web table with macros
but the result is not as expected 
because the result is one column

How to code to make it into 3 columns ?
this is my code

```
for ( x = 1; x <= 10; x++){
    var Volume; 
    Volume =  "CODE:"; 
    Volume +=  "TAG XPATH=//tbody/tr["+x+"] extract=txt" + "\n";
    Volume += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\ FILE=try.csv" + "\n";
    iimPlay(Volume);
    }
```

this is extract result

[image]

```
Browser Firefox 48.0
iMacros for Firefox 8.9.7
Windows 10 32-bit Operating system
```

Comment: Thanks for adding your FCI, that makes your Qt a "Quality" Qt/Thread... - For "those" interested, + parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum: https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=31695 - And I'll "possibly" post an "Answer" on this Site, trying to "summarize" a bit the Answer(s) I've already given in the Thread on the iMacros Forum...